# Linux tool for IPv6 unsolicited neighbor advertisements

Tags: linux, ipv6, ndp

Unsolicited neighbor advertisements is necessary to facilitate rapid service address takeover in a HA cluster. For IPv4 (ARP) you can use "arping -U", but so far I've had no luck finding any tool that can do something similar for IPv6.

EDIT:
After searching more maybe the question is: Is this tool needed for IPv6? To me it looks like NDP should be able to solve this by it self.

Comment: Are you trying to force the new MAC<->IPv6 mappings on your local segment's neighbours?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been investigating this too. So called Unsolicited Neighbor Advertisements are still required with NDP, see:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2461#section-7.2.6

On Debian based systems you can use [`ndsend`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/ndsend.8.html) which you can install as follows:

```
apt-get install vzctl
```

Answer (score 3):

parasite6 and fake_advertiser6  are both part of [THC-IPv6](http://freeworld.thc.org/thc-ipv6/)  They look like they would generate the necessary ICMPv6 packets to force L2/L3 mapping changes.

Comment: I will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at libndp:

```
ndptool -t na -U -i ${int} -T ${ipv6addr} send
```

As per my paraphrasing of the man page:

-t na - Send a "NA" or Neighbor Advertisement (equivalent of an ARP response "xyz is at").

-U - this is unsolicited (nobody asked for it).

-i ${int} - which interface to send it on.

-T - What is the target address in the NS/NA message.

send - to trigger sending (the other option is simply monitor).

Comment: It would be nice to explain what all of these options do, so that people can fully understand it.