# How to send/broadcast ipv6-mac maping cache update request for IPv6 IP

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6, arp, mac-address

We can update IPv4 neighbors by using [arping](https://serverfault.com/questions/175803/how-to-broadcast-arp-update-to-all-neighbors-in-linux?newreg=4fad4147be8f4e71b765c481b38af567) command. I have used arping -A -I -c  <interface_name> <IP_address_of_interface> with success.

what is the command to update mapping of IPv6 address and mac on router/gateway/nodes. we have observed when IPv6 address is removed from one node N1(RHEL-7.9 Node) and assigned to other node N2(RHEL-7.9 Node), mac address on router(Extreme Networks VDX 8770) dont get updated. It eventually gets updated but that time is not consistent. for this duration N2 is not reachable to gateway.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the operating system of relevant hosts and routers. You tagged this Linux, but your comments indicate something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For service addresses, implement a high availability protocol that can move IP addresses quickly. For example [VRRP via keepalived](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2020-keepalived-unicast-vxlan).

To manipulate the neighbor cache on one Linux host, use a command like  `ip neighbour flush to ${ADDRESS}`  The kernel will do discovery when it encounters that IP again, do something like `ping ${ADDRESS}`  This does not affect other hosts' neighbor cache. Other platforms and IP stacks have different commands.

IPv6 neighbor advertisement is not using broadcast, it is using a targeted solicited multicast group. One way getting all hosts involved is playing with router advertisements and virtual MAC addresses.  In other words, VRRP.

Edit: ND spec allows for unsolicited advertisements to all nodes multicast. But it is an optional MAY, so you might want to trigger it manually. See also on Server Fault: [Linux tool for IPv6 unsolicited neighbor advertisements](https://serverfault.com/questions/191991/linux-tool-for-ipv6-unsolicited-neighbor-advertisements).

Comment: This is not router or failover case or virtual ip, In this case when N1 who has IPv6-ip1 is shut off, and N2 is assigned with IPv6-ip1, mac table on router is still IPv6-ip1-mac-N1. it should be mac-n2. The router is not linux machine. question is from N2 - what can we do to update new mac on router. doing Ping is not working.

Comment: See edit adding a mention about unsolicited advertisements.  How fast do you need cutover to be?  ND should figure it out in a leisurely few minutes, but seems like that's not fast enough for you.

Comment: ndptool with -T is solution. thanks @John for pointer.